# Magento Bug - Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted

Tags: magento, wamp

I have installed `magento-1.6.1.0` on my wamp local server. And I am getting this error after installation

```
Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted
```

How to overcome this problem??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

have your base url with full URI Schema : http://your.url or https://your.url and note that you cant use http://localhost as cookies wont work so name your host something else like local.host or whatever suits you best

Answer (score 4):

There is a patch which seems to address this issue in Magento 1.6.1.0 for development purposes, at least to allow me to do some basic testing using a local installation. The patch and instructions are available from http://www.danneh.org/2011/11/bug-magento-1-6-1-0-affecting-development-sites-base_url/

I have tried this on a local installation I'm using for some experiments: both the patch and instructions worked first time on my Macbook (I stopped and restarted the web server after applying the patch and clearing the cache folder, then refreshed the start page in my web browser).

FWIW: I've also added another hostname because of the earlier answer to this question - the site loads correctly for both http://localhost/magento/ and http://myotherhostname/magento/

PS: I've made various changes to the default installation and I'm not planning to use it for production purposes.

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar issue.In error report i was getting following.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:67:"Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted";i:1;s:669:"#0 D:\wamp\www\mymagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php(726): Zend_Uri::factory('localhost/tevet...')
#1 D:\wamp\www\mymagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(313): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
#2 D:\wamp\www\mymagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->_checkBaseUrl(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#3 D:\wamp\www\mymagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#4 D:\wamp\www\mymagento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#5 D:\wamp\www\mymagento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#6 {main}";s:3:"url";s:10:"/mymagento/";s:11:"script_name";s:19:"/mymagento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:4:"demo";}
```

url which I had provided in core_config_data table in database was like following

```
web/unsecure/base_url      localhost/mymagento/
web/secure/base_url         localhost/mymagento/
```

When I changed the urls to following

```
web/unsecure/base_url       http://localhost/mymagento/
web/secure/base_url         http://localhost/mymagento/
```

problem got solved.

Comment: Perfect. It can be one of the reasons

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bug in Magento 1.6.1.0, see here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=12530

with topic:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/263751/#t357355

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving this error because I didn't have `http://` in my base url

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem on Wamp and XAMPP., nearly give up.
Finally find the solution, Magento 1.6 can not work properly with WAMP 2.1 and XMAPP 1.7, I guess it caused by Mysql version, not sure. 
but after I change WAMP to 2.0 i, everything is fine. Magento 1.6 is running well.
Download WAMP2.0i : http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.0/WampServer2.0i.exe/download

I failed to install it on Chrome, but success on firefox.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Install Magento with Firefox, I also got the problem on IE. After installation with Forefox, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.danneh.org/2011/11/bug-magento-1-6-1-0-affecting-development-sites-base_url/

This fixed my problem. MAMP and magento 1.9.0.

I downloaded the tar file, and delete all cookies in chrome, then delete all files under var/cache. Be sure you have more than 1 GB of space on your disk when you refresh the page and go to localhost/magento/

PS: in my core_config_data table, I have http://localhost/magento/ as my base_url (change 2 rows) don't use https, because I couldn't solve the problem (takes a lot of time) with SSL configuration on MAMP.