# Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am getting this error while logging to my site which is on server

> Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted

I am using magento 1.8. I have checked the URL in `core_config_data`, it is correct.

Please help me to solve this problem.

This is the error log:

```
#0 /home/innobmme/public_html/ayurvedachary.com/app/code/local/BTS/1610Fix/Model/Store.php(30): Zend_Uri::factory('localhost/ayurv...')
#1 /home/innobmme/public_html/ayurvedachary.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(313): BTS_1610Fix_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
#2 /home/innobmme/public_html/ayurvedachary.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->_checkBaseUrl(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#3 /home/innobmme/public_html/ayurvedachary.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#4 /home/innobmme/public_html/ayurvedachary.com/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#5 /home/innobmme/public_html/ayurvedachary.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#6 {main}
```

Comment: what is URL for website?

Comment: www.ayurvedachary.com

Comment: have you try http://webdevahsan.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/magento-illegal-scheme-supplied-only-alphanumeric-characters-are-permitted/

Comment: yes i tried it it gives error while logging that the {  is unnecessary at line 712 i.e here {{base_url}}

Comment: check in phpmyadmin for table core_config_data -> web/unsecure/base_url, web/secure/base_url(path) are proper. You might have forgotten to precede the URL with http

Comment: I have checked it there i have written "http ://www.ayurvedachary.com"

Comment: try with http: //www.ayurvedachary.com/

Comment: tried http: //www.ayurvedachary.com/ tried but same result

Comment: Observe the spaces in between also

Comment: no i have written it correct with nospace

Comment: If possible put the screen shot of the configuration of unsecure & secure, Others may help you out

Comment: means the core_config_data table

Comment: no, admin>config. & yes if you cant access the admin

Comment: i cannot login to admin panel it shows same error

Comment: Cleaned cache rm -fr var/cache ?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889286/magento-bug-illegal-scheme-supplied-only-alphanumeric-characters-are-permitte/15894392#15894392

Comment: i have cleaned cache for var

Comment: Muk i have also tried it changing the url [link](http://www.ayurvedachary.com)

Comment: Post your secure & unsecure base_url from DB

Comment: it is http: //www.ayurvedachary.com/ there is no space between http: //

Comment: please do following in  class BTS_1610Fix_Model_Store and function isCurrentlySecure

echo $secureBaseUrl;
die();
$uri = Zend_Uri::factory($secureBaseUrl); and check what it prints.

Comment: Your error itself suggests that there is something wrong with the config. Zend_Uri::factory('localhost/ayurv...').

Comment: hmmm but i am not able to solve it

Comment: it prints localhost/ayurveda

Comment: It shoud display http: //www.ayurvedachary.com/

Comment: yes, but i have changed the url in core_config_data to my site

Comment: Thats why please post both the following records from core_config_data table in the question 

1)web/unsecure/base_url

2) web/secure/base_url

Comment: I was not able to post the image following is the data,                  web/unsecure/base_url
http://www.ayurvedachary.com/

web/secure/base_url
http://www.ayurvedachary.com/

Comment: where is the http://wwww ?

Comment: it is http://www.ayurvedachary.com

Comment: hey it is not printing here, in table it is http ://www.ayurvedachary.com

Comment: Please need a screenshot

Comment: it is not allowing me to send screenshot here because i dont have a reputation of 10

Comment: hey Dushyant here is the url to snapshot od core_config_data http://www.ayurvedachary.com/server.jpg

Comment: hey Dushyant here is the url to snapshot od core_config_data ayurvedachary.com/server.jpg

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem all the above mentioned things were set perfectly but also the problem was not solved. At last i cleared the files inside the var folder and it works.

Hope this will help someone who is facing problem like me.

Answer (score 1):

Check your url in `core_config_data` table `it must have full url`. check there may be missing `http://` .

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error, primary things we should check first:

- Check 'web/unsecure/base_url' and 'web/secure/base_url' entries in the table 'core_config_data' and make sure URL should not contain any white space & correct URL should be there
- We should check the database connection string located under 'app/etc/local.xml' and make sure database, username & password should not contain illegal characters like '[' which can break the XML.